# How to get array size of a global variable using IDApython?

Tags: idapython, array

I can make an array using **MakeArray**.

Is there a function to get the size of the array I've created?

I've tried **GetArrayId** + **GetLastIndex** but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Can you add a sample C or assembly code that you have tried on?

Comment: by "size" do you mean total byte size or number of elements?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky, actually I'm trying to get both.

Comment: @Biswapriyo. I don't have a sample C or assembly code but you can try something like MakeArray(ea,10) to create an array then use GetArrayID + GetLastIndex.

Answer (score 3):

An array is an example of a **data item**. Like all items in IDA (the other item type is *instruction*), it has a starting address (**head**) and **size**. You can retrieve the whole item's size using the function `get_item_size()` (legacy name `ItemSize()`).

To figure out the number of items in an array, you can divide the whole array's size by the size of one element. But how to know the size of element? For this you need to inspect the *flags* of the item (attached to the head byte) using `get_flags()` function. Base item type is encoded in the bits defined by the `DT_TYPE` bits (top 4 bits of the flags) and takes values such as `FF_BYTE` (byte), `FF_WORD` (word), `FF_DWORD` and so on. But instead of checking the bits manually, you can use the function `get_data_elsize()` which return the size in bytes from the flags.

For more info check the `bytes.hpp` header in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @IgorSkochinsky. This was exactly what I did! Almost...
s_id = GetVarStrucId(ea)
s_size = GetStrucSize(s_id)
item_size = idaapi.get_item_size(ea)
num_elements = s_size/item_size

Comment: yes, if your items are sructs you need to get the struct id to determine its size

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky how to do this for stack variables? For example, I have a stack variable: it's an array of 2 DWORD variables. I don't have effective address for them. I can't find it in the documentation: the functions you provided require the effective address.

Comment: @KulaGGin you can use the struct member ID instead of the ea. you need to get the frame struct and check it’s members.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick answer. I tried it yesterday and it worked.